# Auger emission probability?

Tags: spectroscopy

Why is it that lighter atoms are more likely to produce Auger emission and the heavier atoms fluorescence in x-ray spectroscopy? It doesn't make any sense. Lighter atoms should try to resist double ionization, plus there are fewer electrons around which means there is a lesser chance of a photon hitting an electron.

Comment: Your second reason does not come in to play at all - there is already a hole down in the electronic structure. The only question is what the atom does about it. Now, why would a lighter ion resist double ionization more than a heavier ion? Then, consider the range of _where_ holes can be in the electronic structure, and whether it is easy or hard to kick an electron out from deep in a heavy ion's orbitals vs letting loose a photon.

Comment: There isn't any simple explanation or model for the % of Auger emission. Just accept that is the way atoms behave and move on.